# Get result of joining multiple tables as one row

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables:

```
table1:

id | name
---------
1  | john
2  | jack

table2:

id | profile_id | institution
-----------------------------
1  | 1          | SFU
2  | 1          | UBC
3  | 2          | BU
4  | 2          | USC
5  | 2          | SFU
```

If I want to get all the information about a user using his userid, I can simply join them using this:

```
select a.id, a.name, b.institution from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = USER_ID and a.id = b.profile_id
```

which for USER_ID = 1 returns:

```
id | name | institution
-----------------------
1  | john | SFU
1  | john | UBC
```

What I need is actually 1 unique row instead of multiple rows. Is it in any way possible to get something like this? (I haven't seen something to do it but am not sure)

```
id | name | institution
-----------------------
1  | john | [SFU, UBC]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(b.institution),']') institution
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.profile_id
WHERE a.id = USER_ID
GROUP BY a.id, a.name;
```

or with your original query

```
select a.id, a.name, CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(b.institution),']') institution
from table1 a, table2 b where a.id = USER_ID and a.id = b.profile_id
group by a.id, a.name;
```

### Give it a Try !!!

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT does the magic! cheers

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA "...and here my watch ends" :P,
I was looking for this since a long time. Thanks